# How to keep page view count?

Tags: asp.net, session

When I refresh the page, page count does not increase. It is kept in session or any way. For example, in SO, I clicked any qouestion, question view count increase. And I return that question again after look another it is not increase.

What is the logic? And Sorry my poor english. I hope I can explain. I dont know correct tag for this question too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may check the IPAddress of the request coming from and check it. If  A request already came (page view) from this IP for this page, then do not increase the count, else increase.

If you store it in session it can be hacked by different browsers. Ex: If i open the page in 3 different browsers ,the count will be increased 3 numbers. So do not use Session for that.

You can have a table to do that. Have a QuestionId, IPAddress, DateVisited columns. It is up to you to decide whether the visit should be counted if user visit on a different day from the Same IP for same question . Since you have the data in table, you can do the IF condition as per your wish.

Comment: so. I should keep them on my database?

Comment: if you are worried about different browsers from same IP, Session wont help. So you need a persistent storage medium

Comment: Thanks a lot. Second way is better.